# Unique Static Struct Syntax in C?

Tags: c, struct

I came across what I thought was a unique syntax that I've never seen before (I mostly come from a C++ background). I'm not sure what the code is below. My guess is that it's some sort of unique way of defining a struct, but if someone could clearly explain what they're doing here, that would be a great help!

```
static Foo f =
{

    .a = {DEFAULT_FOO},
    .b = DEFAULT_BAR,
    .c[0] = { 0 }

#ifdef BAR
    ,
    .c[1] = { 0 },
    .c[2] = { 0 }
#endif
};
```

Comment: I JUST ran into this like a week ago. It's a GNU extension, I can't remember what it's called...

Comment: This form of initialisation is only available in C99, and possibly also as a gcc extension pre C99.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is C99 initialization syntax.

Note that a final comma is ok in C99, and the snippet could have been written

```
static Foo f =
{
    .a = {DEFAULT_FOO},
    .b = DEFAULT_BAR,
    .c[0] = { 0 },
#ifdef BAR
    .c[1] = { 0 },
    .c[2] = { 0 },
#endif
};
```

Note comma after `.c[0]` and `.c[2]`.

Answer (score 2):

The `#ifdef` is plain old conditional compiling: it makes the bottom two lines disappear if `BAR` is defined.

The `.a = {DEFAULT_FOO}` is the C99 initialization syntax, it provides an initial value for the field `a` of the structure.

The `static`, in C, makes the global variable `f` invisible to the linker, so it will not be available outside the current translation unit or collide with similar-named variables in other translation units.

Answer (score 0):

it's a labeled struct initialization, described [here](http://www.xgc.com/manuals/gcc-erc32-ug/p2node45.html)

the weird dangling comma just after the `#ifdef` is there just to make sure that there's a comma between elements but none at the end wether the last part is active or not.